# How do I read a text file with the following stucture in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text, scanf

I have a file the structure as follow

Each row contain 3 numbers with units. I want only to create a  matrix with size (nx3) and only contain the numbers. I have no clue how I can get rid of all the units. Please help

```
-13.52mm 14.63mm 0mm
-13.54mm 14.67mm 0mm
-13.55mm 14.71mm 0mm
-13.56mm 14.75mm 0mm
-13.57mm 14.79mm 0mm
-13.59mm 14.83mm 0mm
-13.6mm 14.87mm 0mm
-13.61mm 14.91mm 0mm
-13.62mm 14.95mm 0mm
-13.63mm 14.99mm 0mm
-13.65mm 15.03mm 0mm
-13.66mm 15.07mm 0mm
-13.67mm 15.11mm 0mm
-13.69mm 15.15mm 0mm
-13.7mm 15.19mm 0mm
-13.71mm 15.23mm 0mm
-13.72mm 15.27mm 0mm
-13.74mm 15.31mm 0mm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `textscan` on each line: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html

Comment: I try textscan(fid, '%f %s mm %f %s mm %f %s mm'); It can only read the 1st number. Any suggestion?